# How to use thirdparty js library in Angular 2+ without installing types?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I want to use JS library (UMD and global) in my angular application. I have one option use JS library declaration file unsing @types NPM module.

My question is If a JS library is not available of @types module of NPM then How can we use that particular JS library in our Angular 2+ Application.

For example I have integrate moment JS library in my angular Application without installing its @types packege. Is giving error of require module.

Any Suggestions on this that without using @types module how can be integrate JS library?

Comment: `import * as moment from 'moment'` should be enough.

Comment: Moment already ships with its own d.ts files, which is why there is no @types/moment package. Still, it's packaged a little differently which is why the import statement above is the one you need.

Comment: @pascalpuetz, You are right that moment is shipped with its typed version. But I want to know that if a thirdparty js file has not have its type  version then what should be do in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MomentJS and jQuery without installing @types like this:

```
declare let $; // for jQuery
declare let moment; // for Moment.js

@Component({..
```

And use it without problem like this:

```
moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
$('html').css('background-color', '#F4F4F4');
```

Comment: i have tried this but is giving run time error like 'require' is not defined. Any solution?

Comment: Can you show me the code of the page that is giving the error? Since we are not using require I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Previously I was trying the same things that causes the issue but now it's working fine. Thanks for accurate reply.